# Complex variables limit and continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_1\in\mathbb{C}$, then define the sequence $z_{n+1}=f(z_n)$ for $n\geq 1$ where
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{2}+\frac{\omega}{2z}.$$
Show that if $z_n\to\zeta\not=0$ then $\zeta^2=\omega$.

If anyone can explain in detail that would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. If $z_n\to\zeta\not=0$ then, $z_{n+1}\to\zeta$, and by [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) of $f$, $f(z_n)\to f(\zeta)$.

Therefore $\zeta=f(\zeta)$, that is
$$\zeta=\frac{\zeta}{2}+\frac{\omega}{2\zeta}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: could you please solve the entire problem? i couldn't get the hint.

Comment: @kkr See my edited answer. Just solve the final equation.